# How can I cause Zombie Pigmen to drop their golden swords?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to acquire a Zombie Pigman's golden sword without killing them (Something like *trading* with them by throwing another weapon to their feet, such as a wooden sword for example)?

Comment: For what purpose are you wanting to do this?

Comment: @Unionhawk: So that the Zombie Pigmen can have wooden swords, which as stated are better than gold ones.

Comment: To which, I reiterate, for what purpose? Mapmaking would be the only purpose I could see to this, in which case, yes, it is possible. In a survival context, absolutely not.

Comment: @Unionhawk It would be easy to gain golden swords if you could give zombie pigmen wooden swords.

Answer (score 10):

**Yes**, you can trade swords with Zombie Pigman, as per the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Pigman) states, however I just spent almost 20 minutes attempting the act and I could not replicate it, so I am unsure of the truth to the wiki article.

Comment: So, can you at least give them iron or stone swords?

Comment: Can you at least bribe them?

Comment: @Ender check the minecraft wiki,if you throw down,lets say, a diamond sword in inventory form towards a zombie pigman,he will drop his golden sword and take the diamond one.He will deal more damage to you if you attack him then.

Comment: @Ender That **is** interaction, since you are doing *something* to affect them *somehow*. In that case, the answer would be "There is **no** way to interact with zombie pigmen *besides throwing down better swords at their feet and cause them to switch a bad weapon for a better one*"

Comment: I **guess** you cannot trade with Zombie Pigman...

Answer (score 0):

**NO** trading with zombie pigmen unless you die and the pigman picks up your stuff. It works the same way as wither skeletons. (If you want a golden sword, just keep on killing zombie pigmen because they have a rare chance of dropping one.)

Comment: It will be easier to obtain gold swords if you could drop a wooden sword and they drop their gold one and take the wooden sword.Check my comment to Ender above.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** I have seen a pigman drop his gold sword for a stone one. However I tried for ages and had picked up several about a chest full from killing them in the process.

I was playing 1.9